# Python IF statement chain error, can I use non-boolean's in this way?

Tags: python

Python newbie here, unsure if this is the correct method but i'm having issues when trying to get the following to run:

```
from Meal_Options import usual_meals, healthy_meals, hot_meals, other_meals, lunch_meals, fast_food_meals

print("Hello! Lets decide what you want for lunch! Please answer the first question.")
lunch_tea = input("Is it lunch, or tea? ").lower()

if lunch_tea == "lunch":
    print(*lunch_meals, sep="\n")

elif lunch_tea == "tea":

    healthy = input("Healthy or not healthy? ").lower()
    if healthy == "healthy":
        food_type = input("Do you want spicy or not spicy? ").lower
        if food_type == "not spicy":
            print(*healthy_meals, sep="\n")
            print(*usual_meals, sep="\n")
            print(*other_meals, sep="\n")
        elif food_type == "spicy":
            print(*hot_meals, sep="\n")

    elif healthy == "not healthy" or "unhealthy":
        pizza_chinese_indian = input("Do you want pizza, chinese or indian? ").lower
        if pizza_chinese_indian == "pizza":
            print(*fast_food_meals)
        elif pizza_chinese_indian == "chinese":
            print(*fast_food_meals)
        elif pizza_chinese_indian == "indian":
            print("Ok, Korma it is")

    elif lunch_tea != "tea" or "lunch":
        print("\n" "Invalid input, please enter 'Tea' or 'Lunch'")

    finished = input("Are you happy with your selection? ").lower
```

Output:

```
Hello! Lets decide what you want for lunch! Please answer the first question.
Is it lunch, or tea? tea
Healthy or not healthy? not healthy
Do you want pizza, chinese or indian? chinese
Are you happy with your selection? no
```

Why does the code not print anything when answering "*pizza*", "*chinese*" or "*indian*" and just moves onto "Are you happy with your selection?"

Comment: try again ... this time answer `unhealthy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main issue here is that you are forgetting to add the `()` after the `str.lower` method.

```py
from Meal_Options import usual_meals, healthy_meals, hot_meals, other_meals, lunch_meals, fast_food_meals

...

if lunch_tea == "lunch":
    print(*lunch_meals, sep="\n")

elif lunch_tea == "tea":

    ...

    if healthy == "healthy":
        food_type = input("Do you want spicy or not spicy? ").lower()

        ...

    elif healthy == "not healthy" or "unhealthy":
        pizza_chinese_indian = input("Do you want pizza, chinese or indian? ").lower()
        ...

    ...

    finished = input("Are you happy with your selection? ").lower()
```

I've copied only the relevant code in order to highlight exactly where the issues are.

Answer (score 2):

Your second argument `or "lunch"` will always evaluate to `True` since it's a string of a non-zero length.

Should be

```
elif lunch_tea != "tea" or lunch_tea != "lunch":
```

or, even better:

```
elif lunch_tea not in ("tea", "lunch"):
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably want `in` or to have something like

```py
if healthy == "not healthy" or healthy == "unhealthy"
```

The problem is that you're forming a structure like

```
if healthy == "not healthy" or "unhealthy"
if (var == test) or (True):
```